# Change keyframe interval losslessly to produce mpeg-dash content

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash, ffprobe, mkv

I have a case where i have a mkv file encoded to a 2.5 GB file with x264/CRF settings, in this file group of pictures are not of equal duration (i.e 2,4 or 6 seconds ...).

Now i want to create a mpeg-dash version of the file by extracting the video track to mp4 and set the keyframe interval to 2sec losslessly preserving size (minus other audio and subtitle tracks)

What i already have that work:

Fix keyframe to 2s with x264:

```
-codec:v libx264 -force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)' -movflags faststart
```

But it require also encoding settings that change the quality:

```
-b:v 3500k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 3500k
```

In this case i don't need to change the quality from CRF encoding, just change keyframe interval and set faststart flag.

note:
I have detailed bitrate informations about the file obtained by parsing output of ffprobe: average, min and max bitrate in kb/s.
Please avoid solution using -crf 0, mpeg-dash files are later crypted using MP4Box that crash with CRF encoded files.

How can i do this using ffmpeg  ?

Edit:

Sorry my question is not clear, i'm fine with re-encode, i want to preserve quality as much as possible.

Using a little more than source mean bitrate for the `-b:v` parameter the resulting file size is almost same as source, metric test results are not as good i expect:

```
PSNR 41.03 (expected 44+)
VMAF 76.32 (expected 92+)
```

Is my bitrate approch good ? Is there anything i can try to improve metric results ?

Comment: You can't change keyframe placement without re-encoding.

Comment: @Gyan thank you, i'm fine with re-encode, i'm trying to achieve the best result. I edited my question.